# How to add character after a regex match is found

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add a closing bracket to the math expression within the string

```
var str = "solve this now Math.sqrt(345+6 is good but Math.sin(79 is better."; 
var patt1 =  /\((d+)/g;
var result = str.match(patt1);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
```

The match patter displays (345 and (79. Without changing the content, how can I add a closing bracket so the string look like;

```
var str = " solve this now Math.sqrt(345)+6 is good but Math.sin(79) is better.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead assertion.

```js
var str = "solve this now Math.sqrt(345+6 is good but Math.sin(79 is better."; 
console.log(str.replace(/(\(\d+)\b(?!\))/g, "$1)"))
```

`(\(\d+)` capture `\(` and one or more digits

`(?!\))` only if the match wasn't followed by closing brace `)`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the an opening brace if followed by numbers, but not by its closing brace after numbers

```
var str = "solve this now Math.sqrt(345+6 is good but Math.sin(79 is better.";
var output = str.replace( /\([\d]+(?!=\))/g, r => r + ")");
```

**Output**

> solve this now Math.sqrt(345)+6 is good but Math.sin(79) is better.

**Demo**

```js
var str = "solve this now Math.sqrt(345+6 is good but Math.sin(79 is better.";
var output = str.replace(/\([\d]+(?!=\))/g, r => r + ")");
console.log(output);
```

You can include `.` to allow decimals as well

```
var str = "solve this now Math.sqrt(345.5+6 is good but Math.sin(79.33 is better (232.";
var output = str.replace( /\(\d+(\.(\d)+)?(?!=\))/g, r => r + ")");
```

**Output**

> solve this now Math.sqrt(345.5)+6 is good but Math.sin(79.33) is better (232).

**Demo**

```js
var str = "solve this now Math.sqrt(345.5+6 is good but Math.sin(79.33 is better (232.";
var output = str.replace( /\(\d+(\.(\d)+)?(?!=\))/g, r => r + ")");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Can you please elucidated what the r => signifies and how it probably added the closing bracket? Is it somewhat a constant that comes in pair with (?!= \)

Comment: r is the arguments for the replacer function.